# Why did the Leaf Village invite the Village Hidden by Sound for the Chunin exams?

Tags: naruto

I am currently watching *Naruto Shippuden* and just watched the episode where in the past,

> Orochimaru said to Kabuto that he is going to create the Village Hidden by Sound.

My question is, if the people from Konoha (Hidden Leaf Village) know that

> the Sound Village is Orochimaru's village,

then why did they invite ninjas from the Sound to compete in the Chunin exams? Was it not common knowledge that

> Sound Village was Orochimaru's village?

If this will be answered further in the *Shippuden* then I will watch it, but I don't see why it would be.

Comment: is this a second Chunin exam in that occurred in Shippuden? because i know Sound Village Ninja (well, 1 team) was invited to the Chunin Exams during *Naruto* (the one that the Kazekage was invited to) but i haven't seen enough of Shippuden to know if they had a second one during it

Answer (score 5):

At the time of the [chunin exams](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Ch%C5%ABnin_Exams), Konoha was unaware the Sound Village was built by Orochimaru. While Kabuto was infiltrating the exams as a Konoha genin, he mentioned the village was quite young and little was known about it.

> [image: Kabuto talking to Team 7]
>   
> <sub>Naruto Chapter 39</sub>

As for why the sound genin were in Konoha, the chunin exams became open to all villages as a result of the Third Shinobi War. Given how the Sound Village was unknown to be Orochimaru‘s cover and appeared to be an average - albeit young - village, nobody though twice about genins taking the exam.